# shell get substring using awk

Tags: bash, shell

i have some string like

1000    AS34_59329    RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93     /ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T1
1073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS34_59329/111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IP
AAPEK-93_1.fq.gz        /ifshk5/BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS34_5932
9/111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_2.fq.gz        /ifshk5/
BC_IP/PROJECT/T11073/T11073_RICekkR/Fq/AS34_59329/clean_111220_I631_FCC0E5EACXX_
L4_RICwdsRSYHSD11-2-IPAAPEK-93_1.fq.gz.total.info       11.824  0.981393
43.8283 95.7401 OK

i plan using awk to get the AS34_59329

```
 dirname= echo "$myline" | awk -F '    ' '{print $2}'
```

but it can't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awk's default delimitier is any amount of whitespace. Therefore, there's no need to specify a delimiter with whitespace (unless, your delimiter is exactly 4 spaces like in your example). Also, you need a little [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html):

```
dirname=$(echo "$myline" | awk '{ print $2 }')
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your string is already white-space delimited, there is no need to specify `-F`. Try just `awk '{print $2}'`.